# How does Beamer's incremental specification work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows

I am trying to animate as follows:

1. Slide 1 should show only `Bullet 1`
2. Slide 2 should add `root` and `child1`
3. Slide 3 should add `child2`
4. Slide 4 should add `Bullet 2`

Thanks in advance.

> ```
> \documentclass{beamer}
> \mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}
>
>
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage{tikz}
> \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
>
> %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
> \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
> \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
>
> %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
> \begin{document}
> \begin{frame}
>
> \begin{itemize}[<+->]
> \item Bullet 1
>
> \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
>
> \node (root) [process] {root};
> \node (child1) [process, below of=root, xshift=-4cm] {child1};
> \draw [arrow] (root.south) -- (child1.north);
>
>
> \node<+(1)-> (child2) [process, below of=root, xshift=4cm] {child2};
> \draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root.south) -- (child2.north);
>
>
> \end{tikzpicture}
>
> \item Bullet 2
> \end{itemize}
> \end{frame}
>
> \end{document}
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 2 :Some explanations on incremental overlays specifications

The specifics of overlays can be **absolute** or **relative**.

### When they are absolute:

we put the slide number as `<3>` which means that this command will be visible on `slide #3`.

### When they are relative:

the **value of the counter** `beamerpauses` is represented by the `+` symbol (Please note the `+` sign is not an addition).

So if the slide is `number 3` and an order:

- specifies `<+->`, then this is expanded to `<3->`;
- specifies `<+(1)->`, then this is expanded to `<4->`;
- specifies `<+(-1)-+>`, then this is expanded to `<2-3>`;

The other symbol to understand is the `dot symbol .` When presented in an overlay specification, it represents the **previous value of the counter**.

So if the slide is number 3 and an order:

- specifies `<.->`, then this is expanded to `<2->`;
- specifies `<.(1)->`, then this is expanded to `<3->`;
- specifies `<.(-1)-.>`, then this is expanded to `<1-2>`;

## Update 1: With Incremental Specifications

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}%[<+->]
\item<1-> Bullet 1

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node<+(1)-> (root) [process] {root};
\node<.(1)-> (child1) [process, below of=root, xshift=-4cm] {child1};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root.south) -- (child1.north);


\node<+(1)-> (child2) [process, below of=root, xshift=4cm] {child2};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root.south) -- (child2.north);


\end{tikzpicture}

\item<+(1)-> Bullet 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

## Old answer: With overlay specifications

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Bullet 1

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node<2-> (root) [process] {root};
\node<2-> (child1) [process, below of=root, xshift=-4cm] {child1};
\draw<2-> [arrow] (root.south) -- (child1.north);


\node<+(1)-> (child2) [process, below of=root, xshift=4cm] {child2};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root.south) -- (child2.north);


\end{tikzpicture}

\item<4-> Bullet 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Seems like I am confusing overlay and incremental specifications. Maybe you can point to some nice resource which explains with examples specifically about incremental specifications (only and not overlay specs). Thanks!

Comment: @Curious I added some explanations, is it clearer now?

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot for a nice and clear explanation.

Comment: Please change the title of your question so that it really represents your problem and thus allows search engines to index it correctly. For example *"How does Beamer's incremental specification work?"*